# After programmatically adding a Rails route, how to remove it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, rack

Inside my Rails app, I am programmatically adding a route to a Sinatra app like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.append do
  mount MySinatraApp => "/my_sinatra_app"
end

Rails.application.reload_routes!
```

This works nicely. But at some time later on, I'd like to programmatically remove the route, effectively dismounting/killing the Sinatra app. How can I do this?